# How to manually add to swagger's schemas section?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I am using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore and getting this schemas section out of the box:
[image: screenshot of swagger schemas]

My response schema looks empty but it is really that I return subclasses. How can I add them to this section?

I have this request model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using static Assignment_1.AppGlobals;

namespace Assignment_1
{
    public class ExecuteMoveRequest: IValidatableObject, ICloneable
    {
        public int? Move { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public BoardSymbol AzurePlayerSymbol { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public BoardSymbol HumanPlayerSymbol { get; set; }

        [MinLength(9)]
        [MaxLength(9)]
        public BoardSymbol[] GameBoard { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
//...
```

I am using this for my response models:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using static Assignment_1.AppGlobals;

namespace Assignment_1
{
    public interface ExecuteMoveResponse
    {
    }

    [KnownType(typeof(ValidExecuteMoveResponse))]
    public class ValidExecuteMoveResponse: ExecuteMoveRequest, ExecuteMoveResponse
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    [KnownType(typeof(InProgressExecuteMoveResponse))]
    public class InProgressExecuteMoveResponse : ValidExecuteMoveResponse
    {
    }

    [KnownType(typeof(WonExecuteMoveResponse))]
    public class WonExecuteMoveResponse : ValidExecuteMoveResponse
    {
        [Required]
        public BoardSymbol Winner { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int[] WinPositions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate those classes in different files first.
Second try to add before Your classes this comments:

```
/// <summary>
/// Description for Your class
/// </summary>
[KnownType(typeof(InProgressExecuteMoveResponse))]
public class InProgressExecuteMoveResponse : ValidExecuteMoveResponse
{
    ...
}
```

In some circumstances to display the summary You have to enable it in swashbuckle configuration.
Also try to configure Swashbuckle in this way:

```
  app.UseSwaggerUi3WithApiExplorer(settings =>
        {
            settings.GeneratorSettings.DefaultEnumHandling = EnumHandling.String;
            settings.GeneratorSettings.AllowReferencesWithProperties = true;
...
```

Comment: "You have to enable it in swashbuckle configuration" - what does this mean? I am not writing an MVC app I am writing a web api app, btw. My Startup/Configure has: `app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{SWAGGER_API_VERSION}/swagger.json", $"{SWAGGER_API_TITLE} {SWAGGER_API_VERSION}");
// Serve the Swagger UI at the app's root (http://localhost:<port>)
c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
 });`

Comment: thanks for the details, by the way -- should have thanked you up front :) I just forgot because , I have trouble getting it to work